# Can not understand Java 1.7 PopupFactory source code

Tags: java, swing

Hi this is a private method of PopupFactory class provided in java swing 1.7.0.

```
/**
 * Returns the popup type to use for the specified parameters.
 */
private int getPopupType(Component owner, Component contents,
                         int ownerX, int ownerY) {
    int popupType = getPopupType();

    if (owner == null || invokerInHeavyWeightPopup(owner)) {
        popupType = HEAVY_WEIGHT_POPUP;
    }
    else if (popupType == LIGHT_WEIGHT_POPUP &&
             !(contents instanceof JToolTip) &&
             !(contents instanceof JPopupMenu)) {
        popupType = MEDIUM_WEIGHT_POPUP;
    }

    // Check if the parent component is an option pane.  If so we need to
    // force a heavy weight popup in order to have event dispatching work
    // correctly.
    Component c = owner;
    while (c != null) {
        if (c instanceof JComponent) {
            if (((JComponent)c).getClientProperty(
                        PopupFactory_FORCE_HEAVYWEIGHT_POPUP) ==   Boolean.TRUE) {
                popupType = HEAVY_WEIGHT_POPUP;
                break;
            }
        } else if (c instanceof Window) {
            Window w = (Window) c;
            if (!w.isOpaque() || w.getOpacity() < 1 || w.getShape() != null)  {
                popupType = HEAVY_WEIGHT_POPUP;
                break;
            }
        }
        c = c.getParent();
    }

    return popupType;
}
```

My question is, in the comment it says that,

```
    // Check if the parent component is an option pane.  If so we need to
    // force a heavy weight popup in order to have event dispatching work
    // correctly.
```

But when i look that code fragment closely ,even a component(owner) placed  in a JInternalFrame (which is placed in a DesktopPane in JFrame) ends up in the

popupType = HEAVY_WEIGHT_POPUP

it doesn't tally with the comment.Please someone explain this
Thank you.

Comment: We didn't write the comment. Why do you care? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to solve a paint issue in a popup,it is not practical to bring here my original problem problem i need to provide a huge code base.so i am trying to understand the java swing behavior to get some clue. according to this source code swing will always produce heavy-wight popup if the application main window is a JFrame. but i feel i missed something.

Comment: `it is not practical to bring here my original problem problem i need to provide a huge code base` - well you need to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've located the corresponding section in the Java 8 source. There has been a small change to method's behavior:

```
// Check if the parent component is an option pane.  If so we need to
// force a heavy weight popup in order to have event dispatching work
// correctly.
Component c = owner;
while (c != null) {
    if (c instanceof JComponent) {
        if (((JComponent)c).getClientProperty(
                    PopupFactory_FORCE_HEAVYWEIGHT_POPUP) == Boolean.TRUE) {
            popupType = HEAVY_WEIGHT_POPUP;
            break;
        }
    }
    c = c.getParent();
}
```

So if I may speculate, either

1. The comment is the by product of a prior version, and does not describe the way things are done now. *Note they changed the method for Java 8, yet the comment remains verbatim.*
2. The method was written to be extensible to further types, but initially and mainly "option panes" will have `PopupFactory_FORCE_HEAVYWEIGHT_POPUP` set to true.

Comment: i accept this as the correct answer , my question request a explanation about the comment. this second point explains it. thanks.

Comment: @hunter, thanks but from what else you've said it now doesn't sound like this method is going to be your problem. Best of luck.